# Flex swf write to local file if given authorization by the end user

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, mxml

Is it possible to write to a local file 'example.txt' from a Flex swf? [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) class is available in Adobe AIR, not in Flex. I want to write to from a swf,not AIR application.

I am developing a kiosk type application which has to log user interaction data to a text file on the machine.

Is there a code example for doing this?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6167e-7fff.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6167e-7ff9

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) to save a file with user confirmation.  You can also use FileReference to load a file specified by the user.  Or, you can use a SharedObject to save information without a dialog.

Comment: this is for automatic background logging which the user can't see.user confirmation is for allowing a given folder location to be the secured location.